# LiteDB - Selecting multiple entries with one id

Tags: c#, litedb

Okay, apologies if the title is misleading, I couldn't find the right wording for it.

So I have a collection from which I want to count all entries with `UserId` where the `StatusId` is a value.

I'm looking for something similar/the same as the SQL query below.
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Warns WHERE UserId = uId AND StatusId = sId;`

Does something like that exist for LiteDB?

Comment: Have you bothered checking/reading the LiteDB documentation? (https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/wiki/Queries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Count` method directly:

```
var count = collection.Count(Query.EQ("Field", "Value"));
```

Or use the standard collection methods:

```
var count = query.Run(...).LongCount();
```